# Defining arrays in single line in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, declaration

I am trying to declare multiple arrays in a single line. But I am taking this error. (Cannot set property "0" of undefined)

```
var photos,tags = new Array();

flickrJSON.items.forEach(function(item, index) {
    photos[index] = item.media.m;
    tags[index] = item.tags;
});
```

Why I take this error? Can somebody explain? and How can I fix it

Comment: Can you use ES6?

Comment: Just for the sake of interpreting the error, writing: `var photos,tags = new Array();` is the same as writing `var photos; var tags = new Array();`. Hence the error (photos is `undefined`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to use *two* arrays there - an array named `photos`, and an array named `tags`, so you need to use `new Array` (or, preferably, `[]`) *twice*:

```
var photos = [], tags = [];
```

In your original code, `var photos,` will result in `photos` being `undefined`, no matter what comes after the comma.

If you wanted to create a *lot* of arrays at once and didn't want to repeat `= []` each time, you could use `Array.from` with destructuring to keep code DRY:

```
const [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5] = Array.from({ length: 5 }, () => []);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using ES6 you can:

```
let [photos, tags] = [[], []];
```